# PHP cURL says Moved Permanently when POSTing to a virtual host

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to POST some data with PHP cURL to a local site that's using virtual hosts to have a custom domain `http://example.local`, but the result seems to be a `Moved Permanently`. How could I get this to work?

This is my current code:

```
$url = "http://example.local/paypal_ipn.php"
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, substr_count($req,'&')+1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I've tried to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` as true, but that just follows without the POST data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` instead of `CURLOPT_POST` like;

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

And one more thhing, you need to add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
```

3 means `follow redirect with the same type of request both for 301 and 302 redirects.`

By doing this, second request will be as POST request as well. Note that, `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR` implemented in PHP 5.3.2 [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49571)

Comment: Is there a way to identify the new url to follow ?

Comment: @famas23 why do you need that? I haven't used that notation, but at that time you need to disable this redirect option and put your own logic. At least I know there is no such an option to those options I provided above

Answer (score 35):

try it

```
//** add options **//

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "your_var");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);

curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true) line solves my problem.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Comment: Is there a way to identify the new url to follow ?

Comment: Even though curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true) will solve the problem, but if you have any variable need to send over POSTFIELDS, you will need curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3); line as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set PHP cURL to follow location to true

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```