# How avoid Moved Permanently The document has moved here

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I'm in a site and I would call an API that is in another site. So I build a curl

```php
$url = ........
$curl_data = array('name'=>$name);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_data);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

so when I execute the curl I print the value "$output" and I obtain Moved Permanently The document has moved here. This is wrong because I would call this api I would obtain value and come back to the page when the process started. Anyone can help me?

After a day I resolve add this line before to call the function:

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL if it is indeed throwing error 301 (move permanently). Use fiddler  since it can capture HTTP error codes.

Comment: yes... but I don't understand why it gives me this 301

Comment: what is the URL? Are you using a rewrite engine?

Answer (score 0):

see this [PHP cURL says Moved Permanently when POSTing to a virtual host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296828/php-curl-says-moved-permanently-when-posting-to-a-virtual-host)

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me by adding this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, You can fix it by changing your url prefix from http to https (if it was http otherwise change it to http)

The problem is in .htaccess

Something like

```
RewriteRule ............ [R=301,L]
```